# Google Sheets API in C++

Tags: google-sheets-api

Is there a way to integrate the api in c++?? I was looking for a way to read from an online google spreadsheet and I need it to be in C++, but the google available library seems to be outdated and is not recommended to use anymore, what can I do??

Answer (score 3):

There is no official Google C++ API Client.

You have a couple of options:

1. Embedded another language, like [Python](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/embedding.html), into C++ and use that for the API calls.
2. Call the API endpoints with your own HTTP methods.
3. Switch to a language with a [supported API Client](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library).

Hope this helps.